# Copy A Folder With A Subfolders in R

Tags: r

I have a folder containing several subfolders. I just want to copy the whole folder with all subfolders and containing subfiles. Is there a simpler way then using file.copy() for each single subfolder? A more advanced function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a relatively recent version of r, you can use `file.copy(dir1,dir2,recursive=TRUE)`.  For older versions you had to use `system(paste("cp -r ",dir1,dir2))`.

Comment: thx a lot. I tried this ones but I made mistake with the directory path. but it works now.

Comment: Glad it works!  Can you accept the answer so other people know it's solved.  Thanks.